# Rails: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.0.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, docker-compose, bundler

I've Googled this quite a bit, and haven't found anything useful to my situation.

`$ docker-compose up abc`

produces the following in the logs:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.0.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
   from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

The relevant bit from my docker-compose.yml file:
`command: bundle exec rails server`

concurrent-ruby is most definitely installed, exactly where it needs to be. I've run `bundle install` inside Docker so many times, and I've tried adding `gem install concurrent-ruby -v 1.0.5` to my docker-compose command, and it installs just fine, and then still complains that it can't find the gem. I tried adding `bundle install` directly to my docker-compose command, and that fails because of some known issue involving docker-compose and git (I'm using two internal gems). [ EDIT: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2856#issuecomment-236625662 ]

Everything worked fine until I upgraded some Ruby gems, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 23):

I had an issue similar to this outside of Docker.

I deleted the `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle`.

Issue went away.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: After I deleted the Gemfile.lock tried to run bundle and this was the error message: "The deployment settings requires a Gemfile.lock...."

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error with docker-compose. Apparently, it was installing the gem, after running `docker-compose run backend bundle install` the Gemfile.lock file was updated correctly. Still, it would continue displaying this error either for this gem or others.

Turns out that in some cases just running bundle install with docker is not enough. As specified in the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ sometimes after running bundle install you need to rebuild the images. This fixed my problem:

```
docker-compose run backend bundle install
docker-compose build
```

Comment: Hmm, that does not make sense to me ... rebuilding the images after running bundle install -- the effect will be different depending on if the gems are in a shared volume or not.  But either way they should not affect the docker build, because the build step happens before volumes are mounted with docker-compose. 

... ... And just to clarify, `backend` in this case is the name of your particular docker container.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: Set `GEM_HOME` = `BUNDLE_PATH`

Since you're using docker, I also assume you are maybe changing the value of `BUNDLE_PATH` so you can cache the gems? If so, you'll also want to set the `GEM_HOME` variable to this value.

I can't exactly explain why. My theory is that.. something.. is incorrectly using the value of `GEM_HOME` when it should be using `BUNDLE_PATH`, and thus the gems you installed from your rails project's `Gemfile` are not there.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to cache your bundle with docker.  If you're doing that, and you updated some gems you'll bump into this problem.

Delete volume and docker-compose up again.

```
docker volume ls
```

Then:

```
docker volume rm <vol name>
```

Answer (score -4):

Nothing will make it work unless you reinstall the metasploit-framework. I have been facing the issue for 1 week. I have personally tried and its running now.

> $ pkg upgrade && pkg install git && pkg install curl && pkg install
>   wget && pkg install nmap && curl -LO
>   raw.githubusercontent.com/Hax4us/Metasploit_termux/master/metasploit.sh
>   && chmod 777 metasploit.sh && ./metasploit.sh

Comment: I am not sure what aspect of the question caused you to think it is related to metasploit at all. An assumption that the only thing people use docker for is to run metasploit? IDK where you're coming from with this answer.