# tootlcrl error: Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.10 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mastodon

I'm trying to run a `tootctl` command, but am running into a problem with it not being able to detect the required dependency is not present.

```bash
Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.10 in any of the sources
```

I have run `bundle install` and the gems get installed (or are confirmed already installed), but the command still has trouble not finding the

```bash
Using concurrent-ruby-1.1.10
...dozens of other packages
Using rails-settings-cached 0.6.6
Bundle complete! 122 Gemfile dependencies, 225 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `../vendor/bundle`
```

then I attempt the command again..

```bash
me@mastodon-vm:/var/www/mastodon/bin$ ./tootctl media remove --days=7
Could not find concurrent-ruby-1.1.10 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
me@mastodon-vm:/var/www/mastodon/bin$
```

but I'm back to the same problem. What is the typical approach to fix this?

Note: I did try to follow the guidance in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824689/rails-could-not-find-concurrent-ruby-1-0-5-in-any-of-the-sources-bundlergemn), but it broke the entire installation. I was able to save it by replacing Gemfile and Gemfile.lock from Mastodon's source (phew)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log shows

> Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.

Try to install your Gems with

`bundle install --with development test`

or run

`RAILS_ENV=production tootctl`

According to https://rubygems.org/gems/concurrent-ruby/versions/1.1.10 the gem is named "concurrent-ruby". When I run `gem install concurrent-ruby`, it is installed successfully on my computer.

Comment: I do have that env var set globally, and I've previously run it with the env var before the command. I've never tried installing to dev and test, ill try that next. Thanks!

Comment: No luck :( I installed the gems to development and test, too.  Here's a screenshot of the result  https://www.screencast.com/t/5Rzt1JwbgT89

Comment: Not sure what your Gemfile contains but the gem name is "concurrent-ruby" - what happens when you install it without bundler, just running "gem install concurrent-ruby"?

Comment: <--facepalm--> just installing it individually did the trick, lol. That of course is making me go through all the missing gems. I am installing individually, but I think the root probem is where the gems are getting installed to. Can I set a specific target folder when using 'bundle install"

Comment: This is essentially the manual process I am using now (but I at least have a hope of tootctl eventually working) => https://www.screencast.com/t/d2JJNhShBU3 . One thing I did notice is that when running bundle install, things get installed to ../vendor/bundle, but using gem install goes to the default location (and the default location is what tootctl is using). If I can coerce the bundle install command to install gems to the default location, it'll be a one-liner.  (oh, the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are here https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/tree/stable-3.5)

Comment: Cool. Good to read that you could install ruby. To set the path, you can try `bundle config set --local path foo` (where foo is your path), see https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: Yep, I ended up having to write a script to go through all those listed items in the GemFile.lock and installed them. This worked, but now I have a 2nd problem with tootcrl and postgres (postgres throws an exception that the user doesnt have permission). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the docs, I might use that as a sledgehammer. Here's the specifics of my issue. I have confirmed that localhost is in the list, but peer auth doesn't work. I shouldn't be using md5/password because the peer is supposed to have access) https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/issues/22811  (edit for spelling)